# Counting objects within a Foreign Key and ManyToMany in Django

Tags: django, django-views

I'd like to count the objects I have listed.

I would like to count the number of issues within each title.

This is how my models.py are setup:

```
# Edited out
```

Views.py:

```
def titles (request):
    all_titles = Title.objects.all().order_by('title')
    num_titles = Title.objects.all().count()
    latest_titles = Title.objects.order_by('-date_added')
    title_a = Title.objects.filter(title__startswith='A')
    title_b = Title.objects.filter(title__startswith='B')

     ......etc......
```

I need to do this for creators and characters too, except they are in a Many to Many relationship with Issue and the views essentially look the same as the `def titles`

Thank you.

Comment: It would be useful if the models weren't edited out - this question is a bit trickier to understand without them.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To get the related issues for each title you can use the backwards relationship lookup. Since you did not specify a related name in the Issue model where you created the relationship, the lookup is performed using `_set` appended to the lower cased name of the related model. In your case `issue_set`.

```
some_title = Title.object.get(pk=1)
some_title.issue_set.count()
```

However, this is going to perform a db hit for every title you want to count.

You probably want to annotate the titles qs with the count. [**`docs`**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/)

```
from django.db.models import Count
titles_with_counts = Title.objects.all().annotate(issue_count=Count('issue__id'))
```

now each title in that qs has count accessible by using `.issue_count`

```
for title in titles_with_counts:
    print title.title, title.issue_count
```

Comment: Well, doing that shows up with nothing in the template or I'm probably just stupid. I feel my problem is that I am sorting the titles by its first letter in the alphabet, and I do not want it to count all the issues within the title starting with A.

Comment: `from django.db.models import Count`
`title_a = Title.objects.filter(title__startswith='A').annotate(issue_count=Count('issue__id'))` and in your template `{% for title in title_a %} {{ title.title }} {{ title.issue_count }} {% endfor %}`

Comment: Your concern isn't an issue because your filter is applied to the titles, not to the issues. The annotation is going through each title left after filtering and counting all the related issues. The issues are never filtered.